# Jest does not detect my mock call in promise .catch block

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, jestjs, tdd

Jest does not seem to be detecting my mock calls in the catch block. Yet, if don't mock the method `handleError`, I'll receive an error. I have tried multiple ways of doing the returned rejected promise but no luck so far.

I've tried callbacks, Promise.reject, Promise((res, rej) => {})

Code being tested:

```
      module.exports = class PresetDropdown {
    constructor (Api, objectId, titleSort) {
      this.Api = Api;
      this.objectId; = objectId;
      this.presets = [];
    }
  
  
    handleError (err) {
      console.log(err)
      // more functionality
    }
  
  
    get () {
      this.Api.getMany(this.objectId)
        .then((data) => {
          this.handleEmpty(data);
  
          this.isError = false;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.isError = true;
          this.handleError(err);
        });
    }
  
  };
```

Test (Jest):

```
      test('Expect call from handleError after reject promise', async () => {
    // assemble
    // return the class 
    const Module = getModule();

    const mockRejectedPromise = jest.fn(() => {
      return Promise.reject(Error(mockError));
    });

    mockApi.getMany = mockRejectedPromise;

    const module = new Module(mockApi, '1', null);

    const mockHandleError = jest.fn(() => {});

    PresetTemplate.handleError = mockHandleError;

    // act
    await PresetTemplate.get(mockScope);

    // assert
    expect(mockHandleError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // DOES NOT DETECT CALL
    // Test CASE FAILS HERE ^
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `PresetDropdown` class accept an `Api` object, you can create a mocked `Api` object and pass it to the class. Then mock resolved/rejected value for `Api.getMany()` method, so that you can test different code branches.

E.g.

`presetDropdown.js`:

```js
module.exports = class PresetDropdown {
  constructor(Api, objectId, titleSort) {
    this.Api = Api;
    this.objectId = objectId;
    this.presets = [];
  }

  handleError(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  handleEmpty(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  get() {
    return this.Api.getMany(this.objectId)
      .then((data) => {
        this.handleEmpty(data);

        this.isError = false;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.isError = true;
        this.handleError(err);
      });
  }
};
```

`presetDropdown.test.js`:

```js
const PresetDropdown = require('./presetDropdown');

describe('71164955', () => {
  test('should handle data', async () => {
    const mockApi = {
      getMany: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('fake data'),
    };
    const instance = new PresetDropdown(mockApi, '1');
    await instance.get();
    expect(instance.isError).toBeFalsy();
  });

  test('should handle error', async () => {
    const mockError = new Error('fake error');
    const mockApi = {
      getMany: jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(mockError),
    };
    const instance = new PresetDropdown(mockApi, '1');
    await instance.get();
    expect(instance.isError).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71164955/presetDropdown.test.js
  71164955
    ✓ should handle data (14 ms)
    ✓ should handle error (3 ms)

  console.log
    fake data

      at PresetDropdown.handleEmpty (stackoverflow/71164955/presetDropdown.js:11:13)

  console.log
    Error: fake error
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/stackoverflow/71164955/presetDropdown.test.js:12:23)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)
        at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
        at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

      at PresetDropdown.handleError (stackoverflow/71164955/presetDropdown.js:8:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.311 s
```